# java jar files are being deleted in the WEB-INF/lib folder

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, jboss

why does everytime I republish my project, the postgres jdbc jar file located inside the WEB-INF/lib on my .WAR file is being deleted?

I have to recopy the file back into the WEB-INF/lib to fix the ClassNotFoundException exception.

I'm using JBOSS AS 7.1

Comment: you need to provide more details on how you republish your project, how do you generate war file etc to get any help.

Comment: on the server console in eclipse, I deploy the project into the JBoss server, then right click into it and choose republish.. I then start the JBoss server and run the project on server..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That jar is probably missing in the deployment assembly.

In the module Properties->Deployment Assembly make sure the jar is being added.

[image: Deployment Assembly]